# R isn't recognizing a column as a numeric value

Tags: r, dplyr, mean

So in R I have installed tidyverse, readxl and xlsx packages. Then I load my data from an excel file, assigning variable types as follows:

```
full_data<-read_excel("./Blast sequence assignments full.xlsx",
                      col_types=c("Identified Proteins (3404)"="text","Accession Number"="text",
            "Blast protein ID"="text","Blast Accession"="text",
            "Blast taxonomy"="text","Reference A"="numeric","Reference B"="numeric",
            "Anaerobic_24h A"="numeric","Anaerobic_24h B"="numeric",
            "Anaerobic_28d A"="numeric","Anaerobic_28d B"="numeric",
            "Citric_24h A"="numeric","Citric_24h B"="numeric",
            "Citric_28d A"="numeric","Citric_28d B"="numeric",
            "Taxonomy"="text")
)
```

And then I check the variable types and get the following and all of the assignments look correct:

```
str(full_data)

$ Identified Proteins (3404): chr [1:3342] "Casein kinase II subunit beta OS=Tetradesmus obliquus OX=3088 GN=BQ4739_LOCUS9 PE=3 SV=1" "Uncharacterized protein OS=Tetradesmus obliquus OX=3088 GN=BQ4739_LOCUS7 PE=4 SV=1" "DNA helicase OS=Tetradesmus obliquus OX=3088 GN=BQ4739_LOCUS38 PE=3 SV=1" "Uncharacterized protein OS=Tetradesmus obliquus OX=3088 GN=BQ4739_LOCUS55 PE=3 SV=1" ...
 $ Accession Number          : chr [1:3342] "A0A383V1G7" "A0A383V1H7" "A0A383V1J2" "A0A383V1M7" ...
 $ Blast protein ID          : chr [1:3342] "Casein kinase II subunit beta" "Uncharacterized" "DNA helicase" "Methanethiol oxidase" ...
 $ Blast Accession           : chr [1:3342] "A0A383V1G7" "A0A383V1H7" "A0A383V1J2" "Q8VIF7" ...
 $ Blast taxonomy            : chr [1:3342] "Tetradesmus obliquus" NA "Tetradesmus obliquus" "Rattus norvegicus" ...
 $ Reference A               : num [1:3342] 0.0807 0.0152 -0.1225 0.0443 -0.0241 ...
 $ Reference B               : num [1:3342] -0.1262 -0.0034 0.113 -0.052 0.0498 ...
 $ Anaerobic_24h A           : num [1:3342] 0.48 -0.247 0.3 0.244 -0.977 ...
 $ Anaerobic_24h B           : num [1:3342] 0.201 -0.404 0.306 0.249 -1.018 ...
 $ Anaerobic_28d A           : num [1:3342] -0.396 -1.05 0.943 -0.17 0.463 ...
 $ Anaerobic_28d B           : num [1:3342] 0.0993 -0.5398 0.8354 -0.1983 0.3515 ...
 $ Citric_24h A              : num [1:3342] 0.174 0.225 0.136 -0.158 -0.969 ...
 $ Citric_24h B              : num [1:3342] 0.3209 0.2025 -0.1242 -0.0307 -0.7478 ...
 $ Citric_28d A              : num [1:3342] 0.6117 -0.3526 0.964 0.0942 -0.4023 ...
 $ Citric_28d B              : num [1:3342] 0.4925 -0.3011 0.5552 0.0344 -0.3841 ...
 $ Taxonomy                  : chr [1:3342
```

But then I am trying to average a couple of the columns as follows and it tells me that one of the arguments isn't a number, so I'm not sure where the confusion is coming in:

code:

```
full_data<-full_data %>% 
  mutate(reference_avg=mean("Reference A","Reference B"))
```

Error:
Warning message:

```
Problem with `mutate()` column `reference_avg`.
i `reference_avg = mean("Reference A", "Reference B")`.
i argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

And then everything is put in as NA when it should be an average number. I am completely new to R and coding in general. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first that is running you directly into an error, is that `dplyr` allows you to call variable names without the need for quotes. However, since your variable names have a space in them, you need to use the backtick ` character. As it stands, you are literally asking R to establish the mean of string characters, thus returning NA.

The second is that if you want to apply average two variables for each of the rows of your data, you will need to take some additional steps, because R vectorizes by default. To change this default, you'd need to do something like:

```
full_data |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(reference_avg = mean(c_across(c(`Reference A`, `Reference B`)))) |>
  ungroup()
```